# Categories and sub categories for Strapi collection

Tags: categories, strapi, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

Working with Strapi I have a collection 'Events' that has a category 'Music' and the subcategories 'Jazz', 'Funk', 'Samba'.

How do I create a taxonomy system as WordPress has for its posts in Strapi???

Answer (score 2):

This seem to work for me at this moment:

Create category

[image]

[image]

Under "Parent" column there is now dropdown for each sub category

[image]

Create new category and select Parent category

[image]
GraphQL

[image]

I used idea from: https://forum.strapi.io/t/how-to-create-nested-categories-in-v4/16416

Answer (score 0):

The feature is still outstanding https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/8708

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).